# how to add image view inside grid view (Android)

Tags: android, xml, gridview, static, imageview

I cant find how to add the images in grid view statically. i.e Directly in layout.xml.

By searching all I found that we can add image view dynamically in java and not directly in xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a GridView, you need to write a Adapter (Its named BasicAdapter,ArrayAdapter,Listadapter and so on). Each Adapter have a function named "getView(View view, View parent, args)", simply
Override it and return the View you want to have in your GridView.

Comment: yes what you are referring to is dynamically adding the view to our grid view. My grid contents are not going to change, so i want to add them in xml directly.

Comment: as i now it isnt possible because the GridView is extended from AbsListView, this View (class) is abstract so it cant have childs in the XML layout.